# string index out of bound exception while carrying search operation

Tags: android, string, android-layout, android-intent

when I am carrying out a search operation after fetching the contacts,it shows this exception when I type the letters very fast in the search bar and the application crashes.Could you please help me out to resolve this issue.I  am including the portion of the code also along

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newtext) {


    String searchString = newtext;
    int textLength = searchString.length();

    ArrayList<Masterlistmodel> type_name_filter = new ArrayList<Masterlistmodel>();

    /* String text = edtField.getText().toString(); */

    for (int i = 0; i <masterarr.size(); i++) {

        String Name = masterarr.get(i).getName();
        if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(Name.substring(0,
                textLength))) {
            type_name_filter.add(masterarr.get(i));

        }
    }

    type_name_copy = type_name_filter;

    listUpdate(type_name_copy);



    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Comment: paste your logcat log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd point out is that we don't know what kind of object is `masterarr`, So I'll guess is like an ArrayList.

I'd try not to use the `.size()` but the `.length()` method, size is related to capacity and length is related to the amount of items actually in the array.

Also, as @rsinha said, I think a possible mistake is when you try to execute the `equalsIgnoreCase` method and the `Name` variable in that iteration has a lenght shorter than the lenght of the String typed by the user, so I would try:

```
for (int i = 0; i <masterarr.size(); i++) {

    String Name = masterarr.get(i).getName();
    if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(Name.substring(0,
            Math.min(textLength,Name.length())))) {
        type_name_filter.add(masterarr.get(i));

    }
}
```

Try first using `.length()` and if does not work, try the changes in the `for` loop. I see no more in your code I could help with.

Answer (score 0):

You get IndexOutOfBoundsException when you want to access an array index which is out of range. For example:

```
String[] myArray = new String[10];
myArray[10] = "test"; // 10 is out of limits(0-9)
```

Would produce such an exception.

with this:

```
ArrayList<String> result= new ArrayList<String>(); 
Then you can add elements to this list with the following:

// result[i] = trax.substring(s1+4,s2);
result.add(trax.substring(s1+4,s2));
```

It will work for you and it will remove this exception.

Answer (score 0):

'textLength' is length of the search string entered by user. An entry of this length may not be in your master list 'masterarr'. You may try:

```
String Name = masterarr.get(i).getName();
if (Name.startsWith(searchString)) {
   type_name_filter.add(masterarr.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the first statement in the method "**onQueryTextChange**"

```
if(newtext==null) return true;
```

Then try